# How do I update an Intel motherboard BIOS using Ubuntu?

Tags: bios

I'm using Intel DG41RQ motherboard with Intel Core 2 Duo E7400 - 64-bit architecture @ 2.80GHz. Is there any way to update my BIOS?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the [Intel download site](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19952&ProdId=3058&lang=eng&OSVersion=%0A&DownloadType=BIOS) then download the

> Recovery BIOS Update [RQ0017P.BIO]

```
setting Display F7 to Update BIOS.
1. Download and save the Recovery BIOS (.BIO) file to a temporary directory.
2. Copy the .BIO to a USB thumb drive.
3. Plug the thumb drive into a USB port of the target computer.
4. Shut down the target computer.
5. Enable the F7 prompt display:
    a. Power the computer on.
    b. Enter the BIOS Setup by pressing F2 during boot.
    c. Go to the Advanced > Boot Configuration menu.
    d. Enable Display F7 to Update BIOS
    e. Press F10 to save and exit.
6. During boot, when the F7 prompt is displayed, press F7 to enter the BIOS Flash Update tool.
7. Select the USB thumb drive and press Enter.
8. Select the .BIO file and press Enter
9. Confirm you want to update the BIOS by pressing Enter.
10. Wait 2-5 minutes for the update to complete.
11. Remove the thumb drive.
12. Restart the computer.
```

Comment: The link does not work + Intel has removed the bios update files from its download center.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [product page from Intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3058&DwnldID=19952&ProductFamily=Desktop+Boards&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+4+Series+Chipset+Boards&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Desktop+Board+DG41RQ&lang=eng) you can download one of the *Iflash BIOS Update / Integrator Toolkit BIOS Files* and burn the ISO to create a bootable CD or a USB flash drive, boot from it and update the BIOS with that method independently of which OS you are using.

They also offer a BIOS recovery method in case anything else fails.

[This page](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-022312.htm) shows all the available methods for updating your BIOS and on the integrator kit pages you can find very good instructions on [how to use it](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-015474.htm).

Answer (score 1):

1. Get systemrescuecd
2. Install it on usb stick
3. Put bios image file and flash tool on USB stick
4. Now boot from stick, choose 'freedos' as os to boot
5. Flash bios